# Картинка из Assets в HTML не грузится

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
WebView wv_scr4;
String txtHTML = "<html><body>" +
        "<img src=\"file:///android_asset/madagaskar.jpg\"><br>"+
        "<p align=\"center\">Page HTML</p>"+
        "</body></html>";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    wv_scr4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv_scr4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

}

public void onCl_Btn(View v) {
    Log.d("MyLog","txtHTML "+txtHTML);
    try { wv_scr4.loadData(txtHTML,"text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
    } finally { Log.d("MyLog","LoadWV() - Загрузка не удалась"); }

}
```

Результат: 
на экране текст "Page HTML", картинки нет, в логах "LoadWV() - Загрузка не удалась".
Файл с картинкой в Assets (AndroidStudio) присутствует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так надо

```
String txtHTML = "<html><body>" +
    "<img src=\"madagaskar.jpg\"><br>"+
    "<p align=\"center\">Page HTML</p>"+
    "</body></html>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", txtHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Ссылка на картинку должна быть относительной.

Comment: Да, картинка появилась. Благодарю!